# $\liminf$ und $\limsup$ of $a_n:=(-1)^n\cdot \frac{1}{n}-2n^2\cdot (1+(-1)^n)+\frac{n+1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I observed that $a_{2k-1}=(1,1,1,1,1,1,...)$ and that $a_{2k}=(-14,-62.5,-142.67,-254.75,...)$.

Let $L$ be the set of limit points, then we have $L=\{1\}$. But how do I prove that? I guess I have to show that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_{2k-1}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_{2k}=-\infty$. But what even is $a_{2k-1}$ and $a_{2k}$? Do I just have to substitute every $n$ for $k$?

Kind regards,

ParabolicAlcoholic

Answer (score 1):

You are right that by finding those two limits, you have shown that $L=\{1\}$.
But in order to find the limits, you don't simply substitute $n$ for $k$. To see this, you have to remember what the formula
$$a_n=(-1)^n\cdot \frac{1}{n}-2n^2\cdot (1+(-1)^n)+\frac{n+1}{n}$$
actually means. It means that the $n$-th element (say you plug in $n=something$) of the sequence $(a_n)$ is equal to the right side of the equation when you replace "$n$"  wherever it occurs with "$something$". In the case of $a_{2k}$ you have $something=2k$, so you get
$$a_{2k} = (-1)^{2k}\cdot \frac{1}{2k}-2(2k)^2\cdot (1+(-1)^{2k})+\frac{2k+1}{2k}$$
The same reasoning applies for $a_{2k-1}$.